# make iframe google map black and white

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used a google map in iframe.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Madurai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=madursi&amp;sll=10.782836,78.288503&amp;sspn=5.674603,10.755615&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Madurai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;ll=9.925201,78.119775&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Madurai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=madursi&amp;sll=10.782836,78.288503&amp;sspn=5.674603,10.755615&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Madurai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;ll=9.925201,78.119775" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

How to display a google map in black and white color?

Answer (score 24):

It does work, but you should also add the formatting that the different browsers require for grayscale.

`<div style="-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);">`

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9p9w62f/

Comment: I think is better to use `filter: grayscale(75%);` so that you can preserve some styling in google maps.

Answer (score 6):

By [rights](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) the only way to make a black and white Google Map is to use their [Styled Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Your post was tagged with API so I assume a non-iframe option is ok for you. If the inclusion method is not fixed this might will give you an idea of alternative. It is also possible to use the styled maps to generate a Google [Static Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index) which would then also be iFrame friendly.

You could also take a look at [Stamen maps](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/12/37.7706/-122.3782) Which are based on Open Street Maps, but can be used as overlay layers to Google Maps. The form of delivery is not likely possible just through a crafted iframe url.

Comment: This is offers the most flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```
<iframe class="map" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps(...)"></iframe>

.map {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
         filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

This will help

Comment: Given that two people have already posted this suggestion, what do you think your answer adds?

Answer (score 3):

**This one is achieved by using some css**

**Here is working code**

```css
.map {
         filter: grayscale(100%);         
}
```

```html
<iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4917.1193047590605!2d4.4690507720313!3d51.96022102967837!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47c5cb67ae23c02d%3A0xdac4c06bc7904d2!2sRododendronplein+10%2C+3053+ES+Rotterdam%2C+Nederland!5e0!3m2!1snl!2ses!4v1541007683407" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<div>` arround the `<iframe>` and stle it as:

```
webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/? You can configure it as you wish and have an url or json ready to use in your code.